# What is an object (talisman, amulet, salt circle etc.) that hinders or stops an evil spirit called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

What is an object that hinders or stops a spirit (specifically evil) called?  *I.e.* a talisman, salt circle, or any other enchanted object.

Comment: What kind of spirits are involved?

Comment: Does garlic or holy water count? They are objects that supposedly deter the presence of vampires, but they are not specifically enchanted to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A *ward* can define an object that *wards off* evil spirits, negative energy etc. It can serve as a hypernym for such objects, and it can also cover protective spells/enchantments and barriers which is also prevalent in gaming world.

> **ward** *noun* 
> **7**  : a means of defense : PROTECTION
>
> *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ward)*

Here are some relevant examples:

> The concept of the evil eye and the incorporation of its image in jewelry and household decor is a very common idea throughout the world. Many cultures believe this symbol acts as a **ward** and can be used to protect yourself from negative energy and harm. - *[Ladyandtheblog.com](https://ladyandtheblog.com/purchase-evil-eye/)*

> *Shimenawa* are believed to act as a **ward** against evil spirits, and are often set up at a ground-breaking ceremony before construction begins on a new building. - *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimenawa)*